# How to pass OnClick function to React antd Icon React Js

Tags: reactjs, antd

To expand the visual, I need to pass the Onclick function to antd Expand icon(shown below).

[image]

```
const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
};

const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
};

const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
};
```

This is how i passed it to normal button currently.

```
        <div className="expandButton">
            <button
                type="button"
                className="fullScreenButton"
                onClick={showModal}
            >
                Click
            </button>
        </div>
```

Instead of this way can i pass the onclick function directly to react antd icon?

Current antd icon.

```
                    <div>
    
                        <ExpandAltOutlined style={{ fontSize: "150%" }} />
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing an `onClick` prop to the component?  Does the component's documentation have an `onClick` prop?  What specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't able to find any doc related to that. antd doc just has the different icons. So i thought i ask this here, if anyone can have any previous experience with can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an onClick event

```
<ExpandAltOutlined style={{ fontSize: "150%" }} onClick={()=>console.log('hj')} />
```